# TipTap generate JSON from a string

Tags: tiptap

I am trying to generate a node from a string to set as the content for my tiptap editor.

This string could be plain text or a combination of plain text and a URL.

e.g.
`const string = "Hello world https://www.example.com"`

So I tried this:

```
import { generateJSON } from '@tiptap/core';
const output = generateJSON(string, [Document, Text, Link, Paragraph]);
```

However it just creates a paragraph node and doesnt link the url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: generateJSON expects a html string as the first parameter.

In Tiptap you can either work with prosemirrorJSON or html. The transformer cant know if your url should be encoded as a link if you just pass it as freetext. You should either store your data as html or prosemirrorJSON, you could use the plain text as a `view` use in other places or for searching. But you will need to use html or prosemirrorJSON to set the content.